# Truncate table permissions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

What are min permission we need to truncate table ? Apart from DDLAdmin. And what is best pratice to give permission to the user to truncate the user on SQL 2008 R2

Answer (score 4):

Truncate table documentation at books online [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177570%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx)

> Permissions
>
> The minimum permission required is
>   ALTER on table_name. TRUNCATE TABLE
>   permissions default to the table
>   owner, members of the sysadmin fixed
>   server role, and the db_owner and
>   db_ddladmin fixed database roles, and
>   are not transferable. However, you can
>   incorporate the TRUNCATE TABLE
>   statement within a module, such as a
>   stored procedure, and grant
>   appropriate permissions to the module
>   using the EXECUTE AS clause. For more
>   information, see Using EXECUTE AS to
>   Create Custom Permission Sets.

Answer (score 2):

[MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177570.aspx)

> The minimum permission required is
>   ALTER on table_name. TRUNCATE TABLE
>   permissions default to the table
>   owner, members of the sysadmin fixed
>   server role, and the db_owner and
>   db_ddladmin fixed database roles, and
>   are not transferable.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to grant rights (which are excessive, really, and described in other answers) you can escalate permissions within a stored procedure...

```
CREATE PROC DoTruncate
WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS
TRUNCATE TABLE Mytable
GO
```

And permission this instead with "normal" rights